# Como chamar o php em um radio button

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando chamar o PHP para marcar um radio button mas não estou conseguindo.

PHP:

```
if($result['sx_sexo']=="Masculino")
{
    $Result_sexoM ="checked";
}
else
{
    $Result_sexoF ="checked";
}
```

Radio button

```
<p>
     <input  name="sexo" type="radio" id="rd_masculino" value="Masculino" <?php echo $Result_sexoM ?> />
     <label for="rd_masculino">Masculino</label>
     <input  name="sexo" type="radio" id="rd_feminino" value="Feminino" <?php echo $Result_sexoF ?> />
     <label for="rd_feminino">Feminino</label>
</p>
```

erro

> Notice: Undefined variable: Result_sexoM in

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que inicializar ela antes:

```
$Result_sexoM = '';
$Result_sexoF = '';

if($result['sx_sexo'] == "Masculino") {
    $Result_sexoM = "checked";
}
else {
    $Result_sexoF = "checked";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, fala de atenção minha alterei e funcionou vlw